# How to push prometheus metrics directly to VictoriaMetrics?

Tags: python, prometheus, victoriametrics

I'm using python prometheus client and have troubles pushing metrics to VictoriaMetrics (VM).

There is a function called `push_to_gateway` and I tried to replace prometheus URL with VM: `http://prometheus:9091 -> http://vm:8428/api/v1/write`. But VM responded with 400 status code.

Comment: The `/api/v1/write` endpoint expects data in [Prometheus remote_write protocol](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#remote-storage-integrations), i.e. it is used for pushing data from Prometheus to VictoriaMetrics. It is likely you need pushing data via [/api/v1/import/prometheus](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-import-data-in-prometheus-exposition-format) endpoint, which accepts data in Prometheus text exposition format.

Answer (score 3):

It possible to use `push_to_gateway` method with VictoriaMetrics, check examples at gist https://gist.github.com/f41gh7/85b2eb895bb63b93ce46ef73448c62d0

Answer (score 3):

I'm using CSV import at `/api/v1/import/csv` as described here: https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/master/README.md#how-to-import-csv-data

Generating CSV directly from pandas dataframe. Something like:

```
    df.rename(columns={'timestamp': 'ts_ns'}, inplace=True)
    data = df.to_csv(index=False, header=False)

    csv_format = f'1:time:unix_ns{metric_format}{label_format}'

    response = requests.post(url, params={'format': csv_format}, data=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, pls take a look at the client I recently created: https://github.com/gistart/prometheus-push-client

> supports pushes directly to VictoriaMetrics via UDP and HTTP using InfluxDB line protocol

> to StatsD or statsd-exporter in StatsD format via UDP

> to pushgateway or prom-aggregation-gateway in OpenMetrics format via HTTP